# Populating the Current Record in A lookup field in a screen element in Screen flow

Tags: visual-workflow, lookup, screen-flow, flow-screen-component

I'm trying to add a Lookup Field where I try to populate the current Record from where I try to start the screen flow.
I tried various ways to fill it but it is not filling up.
Below is my screen element.
[image]

I tried using the Flow.CurrentRecord as well as a create a separate Resource and try to fill the value from there both of which fails to get filled. Below is the Resource Input_Account.
[image]

The Reason why I create this way is I try to set a Lookup field which the user can change if he doesn't want to fill like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you picking up the recordid variable in the flow?

- Create a variable with the data type of text
- Name it `recordId`
- Select  `Available for input` - this allows you to reference the variable when editing a lightning page.

Like explained here:
https://www.levelupsalesforce.com/get-current-record-id-in-flow

I don't think you need to assign it to CurrentRecord. Just create the recordId variable and use it to populate the Proposal_Account field.

Comment: It didn't work for my flow and I don't know why. So I created a new one using the same concept and it worked. Thanks